error converting mov to mp4 which was created from combined mov/mp4 file sources
Created a video file from images. Added my own music. Split it into 16-second segments with ffmpeg.
Split a video from my iPhone into 1 second segments.
Put phone video bits between my video bits. Saved as MOV. All as expected.
Trying to convert MOV to MP4 using ffmpeg, it throws these errors:
Input contains (near) NaN/+-Inf
Error submitting audio frame to the encoder
Error encoding a frame: Invalid argument
Task finished with error code: -22 (Invalid argument)
Terminating thread with return code -22 (Invalid argument)
used ffprobe to get audio info
what I created
Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s
from my phone
Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 70 kb/s
Assuming audio mismatch is the issue.
Simplest way to make the audio formats of all 25 files match? Or is there something else amiss?
